# How to read/write binary 16-bit data in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, binary

I have to read and write binary data, where each element of data:

- size = 2 bytes (16 bit)
- encoding =    signed 2's complement
- endiannes = big    or little (must be
  selectable)

Is it possible without using any external module? If yes,

1. How to read such data from a binary
   file using read() into an array L of
   integers?
2. How to write array of integers L
   into a binary file using write()?

Comment: Have you looked at Python's struct module?

Comment: I'd say the struct module would be the best place to start

Comment: Using `struct` would be quite inefficient, though, because you would have to unpack the values one by one.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Have you measured that?

Comment: @S.Lott: Yes, while answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227990/fast-way-to-read-interleaved-data) last year.  I don't remember the exact figures.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: """unpack the values one by one""" ? Consider `struct.unpack(byteorder + str(len(rawbytes) // 2) + "h", rawbytes)` where `byteorder` is `<` or `>` as desired. Note: I'm not claiming that this is faster than the `array` way, but I do note that the `array` way sometimes needs an additional `byteswap` step.

Comment: @John: You are perfectly right, I did not remember you can use a repeat count.  The measurements I have done for the linked question do not apply to this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are best off using the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module.  It stores data in system byte order by default, but you can use `array.byteswap()` to convert between byte orders, and you can use `sys.byteorder` to query the system byte order.  Example:

```
# Create an array of 16-bit signed integers
a = array.array("h", range(10))
# Write to file in big endian order
if sys.byteorder == "little":
    a.byteswap()
with open("data", "wb") as f:
    a.tofile(f)
# Read from file again
b = array.array("h")
with open("data", "rb") as f:
    b.fromfile(f, 10)
if sys.byteorder == "little":
    b.byteswap()
```

Comment: More generally, seeing that the OP in effect wants a `file_byteorder` arg, use `if sys.byteorder != file_byteorder: b.byteswap()` in both input and output.

Comment: @John: That's why I wrote "example" above :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from array import array
# Edit:
from sys import byteorder as system_endian # thanks, Sven!
# Sigh...
from os import stat

def read_file(filename, endian):
    count = stat(filename).st_size / 2
    with file(filename, 'rb') as f:
        result = array('h')
        result.fromfile(f, count)
        if endian != system_endian: result.byteswap()
        return result
```

Comment: `array.fromfile()` always takes two parameters.

Comment: Ugh. That's utterly inconvenient. :(

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

`struct.unpack(byteorder + str(len(rawbytes) // 2) + "h", rawbytes)`

where `byteorder` is `'<'` or `'>'` as desired, and similarly for packing. Note: I'm not claiming that this is faster than the `array` way, but I do note that the `array` way sometimes needs an additional `byteswap` step.

Comment: The `struct` way *always* needs an additional `unpack()` step.  The main difference is that you will end up with a Python list, while you get an array when using `array.fromfile()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful for reading/writing the data from a binary file into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

sys.argv[1] = endian # Pass endian as an argument to the program
if endian == 'big':
    precTypecode = '>'
elif endian == 'little':
    precTypecode = '<'

# Below: 'i' is for signed integer and '2' is for size of bytes. 
# Alternatively you can make this an if else statement to choose precision
precTypecode += 'i2'

im = np.fromfile(inputFilename, dtype = precTypecode) # im is now a numpy array
# Perform any operations you desire on 'im', for example switching byteorder
im.byteswap(True)
# Then write to binary file (note: there are some limitations, so refer doc)
im.tofile(outputFilename)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As asked, without any external modules:

```
with open("path/file.bin", "rb") as file:
    byte_content = file.read()
    list_16bits = [byte_content[i + 1] << 8 | byte_content[i] for i in range(0, len(byte_content), 2)]
```

In the comprehension list, we read each two bytes. Then, with bitwise operation we concatenate those 2 bytes. It depends of the endianess for where to write `i+1` and `i`